# Rename Default.png to support iOS4 in Run Script

Tags: iphone, xcode, environment-variables

I have a project with several build targets. Each build target has its own default.png and previously it worked with changing the name of each of these to default.png in my run script.
However with the release of iOS4 I have to modify my script in order to support the Retina Display. Is it possible to get the target device version (iOS3.x or iOS4) and change the name accordingly?

My current build script is:

`cp Default-${PRODUCT_NAME}.png Default.png`

I would like to change this to something like:

```
if (iOS4)
 cp Default-${PRODUCT_NAME}@2x.png Default.png
else
 cp Default-${PRODUCT_NAME}.png Default.png
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't how Default.png works. You just drop both in there. (Default.png and Default@2x.png)